# Chrome performance analysis with long system self time

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am analysing web page performance. Web page contains one handler for "pointermove" event to change "transform: translate(x,y)" of the HTMLElement (with about 10 DOM descendents in total).

In Chrome browser, in specific conditions, "pointermove" is not handled in very performant way -- during "pointermove" there occurs delays and "choppy" changes of transform attribute.

On the contrary, in Firefox everything is performant (in these specific conditions).

In performance analysis in Chrome, I detected long "task"s during "pointermove". It says that web page JS functions (and rendering) took about 1 ms, but "System (self)" took 128 ms.

### Summary tab:

#### Task

- Total Time: 129.76 ms
- Self Time: 128.19 ms

### Bottom-up tab:

- 0.6 ms 37.5 % Update Layer Tree
- 0.3 ms 19.9 % Composite Layers
- 0.2 ms 14.8 % Hit Test
- 0.2 ms 13.8 % Recalculate Style

There is no explanation what task is doing and what is it? What is "System (self)" and why it took so much time? How to resolve such "choppy" behavior?

I expect performant handling of "pointermove" event, like it is in Firefox.

In Chrome, "pointermove" is handled with some long running "System (self) task", which causes bad handling and choppy feeling (delays).

### Snippet / JSFiddle

```
code is here ↘
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ziom1/f8jbyz52/

Comment: It seems to Chrome doesn't work well with translation HTMLElement which contains a lot of text (5000+ words). For first time time (started and finished) translating such HTMLElement with "pointermove", Chrome works well. However, after changing DOM structure (added sibling Element then removed this sibling Element), Chrome works invalid (poorly) with translation due to "pointermove".

Comment: "System" means the browser. The only solution here is to report the issue on https://crbug.com and meanwhile find a workaround by experimenting with various things in CSS/DOM. Obviously we can't help without [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: @wOxxOm ehh... I have added a snippet.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1014988, not sure what workaround you can use other than capturing the element into a `<canvas>` (or `<img>` and using it as a drag'n'drop placeholder).

Comment: It seems that Chrome is not optimized to handle any "transform" of HTMLElement with 50+ nodes content (not only text, but also pure HTMLElements, grid style CSS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue with my Notes AngularJS application that had big text inside textarea. When moving cursor it took ~600ms for `System (self)` in performance tab, the rest was 0 or 1ms.

[image: Dev tools performance Tab]

[image: Browser performance pie chart]

I was planning to create an issue but found this question, then wanted to report a bug to Chromium. But then I've checked how much memory the Chrome uses. I've had a lot of tabs open with a lot of heavy apps. Like multiple YouTube links, MS Teams etc. And pages hidden in groups. I've opened task manager and killed some processes/tabs that had the most mount of memory. And now my app works fine.

I may reach the limit of the browser memory. Note that I have 16GB and running Firefox on that system (with Chrome running) was not a problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a memory limit here. Happening for me with 6 GB free.

Comment: @James I don't think that Chrome is allowed to use all free memory of the system.